# Which command will work instead of systemctl and systemd in AWS linux instance?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

i have a aws linux instance,i am trying to start services from systemctl and systemd but both command is not there in system, my linux version is -

```
Linux ip-xx-x-x-xxx 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 29 01:16:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What services? Does systemd exist?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately we dont have the systemd in the Amazon Linux machines of the 1st version.

They have recently got (Amazon Linux 2 LTS Candidate 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-f973ab84) which will have the systemd in it.

If you are using the 1st version then its not possible to execute these commands.